# Can one make NV centred type qubits from analogus materials in the periodic table?

Tags: experimental-realization, chemistry

Can one replace Nitrogen with Phosphorus and Carbon with Silicon and so on?
What would be the conditions that would preclude such a realisation? Are there any implemenations so far?